# How to flag users on all days before last day

Tags: hive

I have this case on SQL and I need some help:

I want to add a new column on this query, to flag all days less than the user's last day.
So if the user last_day is 1-2-2019 and the date_ 1-1-2019, I want to flag the user on that day because it's before his last_day.

E.g: user_id=A1200 , first_day on (10-1-2019) and last_day (20-1-2019) and he didn't have any records in between, I want to add a new column and set all records from (10-1-2019) till (20-1-2019) with 1 for that user.

This is my query:

```
select user_id,date_, first_day, last_day

from orders g
left join (select user_id, min(date_) as first_day
           from orders
           group by user_id) m on m.user_id=g.user_id

left join (select user_id, max(date_) as last_day
           from orders 
           group by user_id)l on l.user_id=g.user_id
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sample data and expected results would make your question easier to understand.

Comment: Are you using mysql or hive? These are two different database products, with different specifications.

Comment: @GMB Hive, added an example

Comment: you should provide sample data and expected results as tabular text. Please [have a look at this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for how and why.